# Angular $http.delete has no callback when succeding

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs

I'm running some integration tests with Jasmine and a [custom angular-mocks](https://gist.github.com/kyro38/3371aaac54bf6583852f) module (to allow real HTTP calls).

When doing a $http.delete (HTTP DELETE) on a URL, the call is successful (backend received it) but on PhantomJS's side I don't get any callback (the promise aint resolved).

I'm not having this problem with Chrome nor firefox therefore I'm suspecting PhantomJS to be buggy somehow.

Any idea if there is something I could do ?

PS: I already filed [an issue on PhantomJSs GitHub](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12604).

Comment: I'm not using `phantomjs`, but I think I am observing this behavior as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually it wasn't no callback at all. After increasing jasmine's timeout and karma's `captureTimeout` to 60s and waiting for 20sec I finally got my callback.

But It's kinda weird it take so much time with Phantom.